# How to display text in place of URL in a Dribbble shot description

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

I know this is possible because I've seen others doing it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution that works.

Basically, instead of displaying an entire URL in a Dribbble shot description, I would rather have simply the name of the website I'm linking to.

For Example:

Instead of

https://www.behance.net/gallery/64379983/Logo-Design-Commemorative-Logo-Merchandise

I would like the link to show simply as  **Behance**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/64379983/Logo-Design-Commemorative-Logo-Merchandise">Behance</a>
```

[Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/64379983/Logo-Design-Commemorative-Logo-Merchandise)